# How do I inspect the layout of, or an element within, content displayed by a Firefox extension outside of a regular webpage?

Tags: debugging, firefox, firefox-addon, firebug, extension-methods

In Google Chrome, I can right-click on extension content and select "Inspect" to inspect the content created by an extension. For example, Chrome layout with right-click menu displayed:

[image: Chrome layout with right-click menu displayed]

Mozilla Firefox layout:
[image: My extension's Mozilla Firefox layout]

How I can inspect the layout of the content my extension has created in Firefox?

Answer (score 3):

**Non-Webpage content (extension pop-ups, extension windows, Firefox UI, or anything else):**
To inspect the content created outside of a webpage by an extension (or *anything* within Firefox), you can use the [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) [DOM Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Add-ons/DOM_Inspector). I also installed the [Element Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/element-inspector/) extension, which enables you to open the DOM Inspector on any element with a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + right-click. You can also open the DOM Inspector from the Menu Bar->Tools->Web Developer->DOM Inspector.

The DOM Inspector:
[image: DOM Inspector]
Inspecting a window created by an extension:
[image]

From the DOM Inspector menu bar you can select which open *Content Document*, or *Chrome Document* you desire to inspect. However, Element Inspector makes it easy to directly open DOM Inspector on the content you are interested in with just a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + right-click instead of having to open the DOM Inspector and then selecting the correct document and then find the correct element.

**Normal Webpages:**
For normal web pages you can use the Inspector:
By default, you can right-click and select "Inspect Element (Q)".  A default profile on Windows 7x64 running Firefox 45:

[image: Firefox right-click menu]

Which opens the Inspector on the element over which you are hovering:

[image: Web page with inspector]

If you have installed Element Inspector without DOM Inspector, it will open the normal inspector (as in the image above) with a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + right-click on the element you desire to inspect.

You can also open the Inspector by the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, or from the menu bar->Tools->Web Developer->Inspector.

By the way: Your question, as originally written, appears to demonstrate that you expect the user interface for Chrome and Firefox to be the same. This is an unreasonable expectation. It is unreasonable to expect two different programs to have the same user interface. While it sometimes happens that one program will adopt aspects of another program's user interface, it does not happen all that often. Expecting it to have happened is not a viewpoint which will get you very far. While there are often similarities between programs that do somewhat the same thing, the user interface is usually different.

Comment: @Mayken I found your answer useful and wanted to contribute, I found another hidden method to edit the Chrome GUI in Firefox in Bugzilla: It's already possible to load a Browser Toolbox in a tab to edit the chrome via:
  `about:devtools-toolbox?type=process`
And a Browser Content Toolbox via:
  `about:devtools-toolbox?type=process&id=1`

You "just" have to be careful when using the Debugger panel.

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect the Firefox UI using the [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox).

Note that you can currently only inspect elements by first enabling the inspector and then clicking the element. There is currently no right-click option to inspect an element. This is requested in [bug 972404](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=972404).